# AWS CodeDeploy pros/cons

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

We have a Enterprise setup (large) with a wide range of applications- legacy to somewhat modern: Node, Tomcat, WebLogic, Kafaka, Cassandra, DBs, some Docker, etc etc. We have a hybrid setup moving more and more onto AWS. We currently use Git, Jenkins, Chef, etc for our build/deploy. We do have the usual audit/compliance requirements. Our apps are typical custom multi-tier apps- so essentially sequencing and dependencies. And we do periodic releases (including gating/approvals), so not yet in the micoservices world of many deploys/day.

Now I am trying to evaluate AWS CodeDeploy as a tool for AWS deployment. Based on product spec/docs it can do hybrid (on-prem and cloud)- that sounds great. It can work with Jenkins (has plugin) or I can consider AWS Codepipeline as alternative or addon to Jenkins. I can see CodeDeploy integrates very well with the AWS ecosystem (but of course) – Autoscaling, etc.

My question is: What are the **inherent limitations** of CodeDeploy- what does it not do well, any gotchas that we need to be aware of.

One limitation I see is it can’t do multi-tier apps – each service/app would need its own Deployment Group. *It's not possible to control the order in which deployments occur if more than one deployment attempts to run at the same time.*
This actually is an **important requirement for us** based on the nature of our apps and release practices that we have.

**Code Promotion**: Based on the description I can see CodeDeploy in itself does not have any code promotion ability. We possibly would have to use Jenkins or CodePipline for it. (?)

**Event hooks**: I can see it has event hooks and I can script onto the events. Is that the best practice in AWS. So likely I would install my Software (Apache, etc) *BeforeInstall* kind of an event (?)

**Packaging** : We have to package the entire deploy content (along with the AppSpec file) and copy it it a repoistory (S3/Git) rather than picking the content directly from Git or Nexus. Does this become a issue in real life.

**Or simply stay out of CodeDeploy** and stick with Jenkins/Chef/CloudFormation (or OpsWorks/BeanStalk).

If people can share pros/cons of CodeDeploy with some actual experience, that would be most helpful. *(Hopefully the entire community can gain).*

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this article: https://vtimd.medium.com/aws-codepipeline-the-good-and-the-bad-2bd607102c2